# sort data by filters, react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a card where it shows me data that has been passed to me, but I have to sort them with several different filters using buttons, the order would be from highest to lowest and from lowest to highest

```
const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
      24 hours
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
      48 hours
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
      72 hours
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

function Menutop(props) {
  const [percent, setPercen] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (percent === 100) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        props.showTiendas(true);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      props.showTiendas(false);
    }
  }, [percent, props]);

  return (
    <>
      <Progress value={percent} onUpdate={setPercen} duration={16} />
      <div className="flex items-center bg-dark-04 px-4 py-3">
        <div className="flex w-3/12">
          Name
          <BsArrowUpDown className="text-base ml-2" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-1/6 justify-center items-center">
          capacity
          <BsArrowUpDown className="text-base ml-2" />
        </div>
        <div className="card flex w-1/12 justify-center items-center">
          <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
            <Button>
              Capacity alert <DownOutlined />
            </Button>
          </Dropdown>
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-1/6 justify-center items-center">
          visitor
          <BsArrowUpDown className="text-base ml-2" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-1/6 justify-center items-center">
          Distancing alert
          <BsArrowUpDown className="text-base ml-2" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-1/6 justify-center items-center ">
          Capacity alert
          <BsArrowUpDown className="text-base ml-2" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex h-3  w-1/6"></div>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setPercen(0);
          }}
          className="w-1/12 flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer bg-yellow"
        >
          <BsArrowRepeat className=" font-bold text-2xl" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Menutop;
```

The filters would be the ones I have put, `name`, `capacity`, `Capacity alert`, `visitor`, `Distancing alert` and `Capacity alert`, the only one that would change from smallest to largest would be `name` that would be in alphabetical order, I still have a button that would be ordered by hour that neither I know how to do it

this is where i show my data:

```
function Card(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const trigger = useRef(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (trigger.current) {
      trigger.current.style.transition = "0.35s";
    }
  }, [trigger]);

  function toggleOpen() {
    if (trigger.current) {
      setOpen((open) => !open);
      if (open) {
        trigger.current.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)";
      } else {
        trigger.current.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(180deg)";
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <div className="w-full flex justify-center px-4 py-3">
      <div className="flex w-3/12 px-2 items-center">
        <div className="w-24 p-2 bg-dark-04 mr-4 rounded">
          <img src={props.store_logo} className="" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center ">
          <p className="font-semibold my-0">{props.store_name} </p>
          <p className="text-xs my-0">{props.store_address} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex w-1/6 justify-center items-center px-2">
        <div className="w-4/5 h-10 bg-green bg-green-700 rounded text-white font-bold flex justify-center items-center">
          <p className="my-0 text-lg">{props.occupancy.occupancy}/{props.occupancy.capacity}</p>
          <p className="ml-2 my-0">{props.occupancy.percentage}%</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex w-1/12 justify-center">
        <Chart />
      </div>
      <div className="flex  w-1/6 justify-center items-center font-semibold">
        <p className="my-0 text-lg">{props.visits}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center font-semibold w-1/6">
        <p className="my-0 text-lg">{props.alerts.conglomerations} Alertas</p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center font-semibold w-1/6 ">
        <p className="my-0 text-lg">{props.alerts.occupancy} Alertas</p>
      </div>
      <div className="card flex justify-center items-center w-1/6">
        <Button className="mr-3">Analytics</Button>
        <Button>Alerts</Button>
      </div>
      <div className="w-1/12 flex justify-center items-center">
        <span
          ref={trigger}
          onClick={toggleOpen}
          className=" w-4/12 flex justify-center items-center"
        >
          <BsChevronUp className=" text-2xl" />
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Info open={open} {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

where I show my data is a component where I send it to call

this would be the data:

```
[
{
    "name": "Samantha White",
    "id": "484567489sda",
    "address": "4116 Barton Creek Boulevard Austin, TX 78735 USA",
    "logo": "https://sssssss.s3.amazonaws.com/ssss/express.png",
    "occupancy": {
      "capacity": 150,
      "occupancy": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "alerts": {
      "conglomerations": 0,
      "occupancy": 0
    },
    "visits": 2721
  },
  {
    "name": "Jacqueline Wells",
    "id": "sdasdx45616a4dsa5",
    "address": "s15035 Highview Road Grand Junction, CO 81504 USA",
    "store_logo": "ssssss.s3.amazonaws.com/ssss/lider.png",
    "occupancy": {
      "capacity": 150,
      "occupancy": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "alerts": {
      "conglomerations": 0,
      "occupancy": 0
    },
    "visits": 2069
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include your data as an array in the state.

After you've done that, you'll have to make a function where that array is reassigned to one sorted depending on which button the user has pressed.

In this last step the [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) will come in handy.